# Installing and using Python egg files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

Im creating a pyspark application to run on AWS EMR cluster which has dependency on s3fs.
I want to install s3fs packages through command line by creating python egg or a zip file or any other best approach.

I tried below to create a python egg file and pass it as a parameter in pyspark but, running into  issue listed below.

```
pip install s3fs==0.2.2 -t s3fs     # Installed s3fs packages locally into a directory
cd s3fs/                              
python setup.py bdist_egg           # Ran the setup.py to create .egg file. The setup.py is below
aws s3 cp s3fs s3://myBucket/prefix/pkg/ --recursive  # Copied all files to an s3 path
```

```
# setup.py File
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="s3fs",
    version="0.2.2",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

Now I to passed the egg file as a parameter to pyspark and tried to import s3fs but running into issue as below.

```
pyspark --py-files s3://myBucket/prefix/pkg/dist/s3fs-0.2.2-py2.7.egg
>>> import s3fs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/s3fs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    #
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/s3fs/core.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name raise_from
```

Any suggestions or alternate approach to achieve this.

Thanks!!